# ASP.NET Compilation Error

Tags: .net, asp.net, compiler-errors

I have a simple ASP.Net application which consist of 2 projects:

- ASP.Net Project
- Class Library Project (contains the data access and
  make simple business validation)

When I compile the ASP.Net project, the compiler raise an error that a method in a class is not exist.

ex.: I have a class called User, this class has a method called AddUser, the compiler says that User doesn't have a definition to AddUser or there is no extension method called AddUser. However, when i point to the method calling in the page and press F12 (Go to definition) It goes to the method definition which indicates that the complier can see the method.

How could this happen?!!!! and how can I solve it?

Comment: Could you provide code samples and error message, please?

Comment: Ususally, when being inside an ASPX page, `User` refers to the [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx) property. Try a full qualified namespace to your `User` class.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compile only class library. After, compile your ASP.net project. I have the same problem, and I finally discovered that my compiled dll file was outdated.

Answer (score 0):

How did you add your reference to the class library - did you add a 'project' reference or did you browse directly to the DLL (the project reference is the one you want).

Comment: Yes Paddy I reference the project